# Cannot parse JSON from Vuex getter in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuex

I have an Ionic Project with Vuex. I have created a store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    user: localStorage.getItem('userdata') || {}
},
getters: {
    getUser(state) {
        return state.user
    }
},
mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
    destroyUser(state) {
        state.user = null
    },
},
actions: {
        retrieveUser(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get('v1/user')
                    .then(response => {
                        const user = response.data.data
                        localStorage.setItem('userdata', JSON.stringify(user))
                        context.commit('setUser', user)

                        resolve(user)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {})
            })
        },
}
})
```

This part works perfect as expected. My localstore holds the JSON string. Now i tried to return the string with the getUser getter JSON.parsed. This doesn't work, because it gives me a parse error which makes no sense, because the string works perfectly fine.

When I try to load the userdata in the vue component like this

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadUserData()
    },
    methods: {
        loadUserData() {
            let userData = JSON.parse(this.$store.getters.getUser)
            this.user = userData
        }
    },
}
```

It returns the JSON Data as Proxy ( ?? )

```
Proxy {id: 27, name: "English", firstname: "Harriet", fullname: "Harriet English", number: null, …}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

(it's sample data, so no real name shown ) which I cannot use.
I have also tried to use the state variable, the localstorage content, which did not work...

How can I access my JSON data?

Comment: You should rethink the design, storing a stringified version of your object instead of the object itself isn't a great plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the user data after your API call, you are storing it in localStorage as `JSON.stringify(user)` but you are updating the store with just the raw `user` data. I guess you should update your API call handler to:

```
const user = response.data.data;
const strUser = JSON.stringify(user);
localStorage.setItem('userdata', strUser);
context.commit('setUser', strUser);
```

This should allow you to parse the data the way you are trying to in your component, which should work whether `state.user` has been initialised with the localStorage data, or if it has been updated after the API call.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works. It's strange, because that was a change I tried because of the error and I've only forgotten to revert back.